# Spinning icons work in codepen, but not in browser

Tags: html, icons, css, animated

I'm playing around with code to embed social network icons that rotate on hover.  I am adjusting them for a project, and it works fine in [this pen](http://codepen.io/MarcMurray/pen/cCdBu).  But when I copy the code into Brackets, whenever the page loads, the icons don't appear until you hover over the square.  Anyone have any idea where I'm after going wrong?

HTML

```
<section>
  <ul id='services'>
    <li>
      <div class='entypo-facebook'></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class='entypo-twitter'></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class='entypo-gplus'></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class='entypo-linkedin'></div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

CSS

```
@import url(http://weloveiconfonts.com/api/?family=entypo);
/* entypo */
[class*="entypo-"]:before {
  font-family: 'entypo', sans-serif;
}

html, body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #ECF0F1;
}

section #services {
  text-align: center;
  transform: translatez(0);
}


section #services li {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px;
  list-style: none;
}

section #services li div {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  color: #ECF0F1;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

section #services li div:hover {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
    border-radius: 100px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
    -moz-border-radius: 100px;
    background-color: #303030;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the prefix like `-webkit-` `-moz-` and so on in your `transform` property.

[SEE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ilOTuPa/2)

```
section #services li div:hover {
  -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  transform: rotate(360deg);
  border-radius: 100px;
}
```

Comment: I have since added these prefixes, thanks, but the font still doesn't load until the grey squares have been hovered over.

Comment: I have, its in the second codepen link, when copied into a file and viewed in a browser it doesn't load the icons till they've been hovered over

Comment: Hmm odd, maybe it has to be online to work! Thanks I'll try uploading it.